# Double clicking on Android Studio IDE files does not show the file in the window

Tags: android-studio

Not sure what happened, but double click on file does not open a file in the middle of window, instead, nothing happens.
Tried to uninstall Studio - the same.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dragging and dropping the file into the window?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens. When I double click other files, the top header changes, so it feels like its opening file, but the window itself is hidden somehow

Comment: You could perhaps try these: (1) **Build** >> **Rebuild Project** (2) **Window** >> **Restore Default Layout** (3) Run the program.

Comment: @DavidLee Did not help, sadly. :/

Comment: You could also try creating a new activity and see if that opens up the new one. (I've never experienced this, only with the **XML** file...)